# Getting the selected item from DataGrid on UserControl custom event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid`, which contains a `Button` to delete the item in the list, and a `UserControl` which contains a custom event.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel}" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50" DisplayIndex="0">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                ....
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- UserControl -->
                    <local:MyCustomUserControl ValueChanged="DoSomething_CustomEvent" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50" DisplayIndex="0">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                ....
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Button Delete -->
                    <Button Click="DeleteItem_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the `Click event` of the `Button`, this is how I get the item in the `DataGrid` list and delete it.

```
//this is in my MainWindow
private void DeleteItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    ViewModelItem? obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as ViewModelItem;
    viewModel.ListItem.Remove(obj);
}
```

However, I'm getting `null` using the same method in the custom event of my `UserControl`.

```
//this is in my MainWindow
private void DoSomething_CustomEvent(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e){
    //obj is null here
    ViewModelItem? obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as ViewModelItem; 
    ...
}
```

here is the sample of my UserControl class.

```
public partial class MyCustomUserControl : UserControl{

        #region Custom event when a new item is added into the List 
        public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;
        protected virtual void OnValueChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs e){
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e); // Raise the event
        }

        public class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs{
            public object MyListObject { get; set; }
            public ValueChangedEventArgs(object MyListObject)
            {
                this.MyListObject = MyListObject;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private readonly ObservableCollection<UserControlItem> UserControlListItem  = new();
    
        #region Constructor
        public MyCustomUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this.viewModel; //this is bad
            //instead, set the itemsource from code behind
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = UserControlListItem;
        }
        ...
        
        private void FireTheEvent(){
            List<object> listObject = ...
            OnValueChanged(new ValueChangedEventArgs(listObject)); //fire the event and let the MainWindow know about it.
        }
        
}
```

How can I get the item the same as when the button is clicked?

Comment: As a note on design, it looks odd that MyCustomUserControl knows its parent MyMainWindow. In order to avoid such a dependency, MyCustomUserControl could expose a custom event where it passes its "result" via custom EventArgs. MyMainWindow would attach an event handler to handle the data.

Comment: @Clemens - Everything is messed up, so I made changes.

Comment: @Clemens - Also, you are right, so I used a custom event.

Comment: FYI a standard `EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs>` delegate would match the same handler signature without needing a new delegate type

Comment: You may have explicitly set the DataContext of MyCustomUserControl (or MassIntentionDateTimePicker?) somewhere in its XAML or code behind. That would not only break the standard  data binding mechanism, but also your own code.

Comment: @Clemens the UserControl has another DataGrid, so I have another ViewModel on it.

Comment: @Clemens instead of the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`, it is getting the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` itself?

Comment: Sure, that is what you request by `((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext`. It is not a ViewModelItem, hence the `as` operator returns null - which you could have easily found out by debugging. As said, it is a general programming error when a control sets its own DataContext. Besides that, a control does not need a private view model at all. That is a common misconception when people try to implement MVVM.

Comment: @Clemens updated the `UserControl` class, I have another `DataGrid` in my `UserControl`. instead of setting the `DataContext`, I set the `BindingSource` of my `DataGrid` in the code behind. It is now giving me the expected output but I am not still sure if this is alright.

Comment: @Clemens I see, this works `MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.UserControlListItem ;`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant to say. It is however unclear why you have this private view model at all. The control could as well declare the UserControlListItem collection. "Internal" view models do not make much sense.

Comment: @Clemens actually you are right. `MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = UserControlListItem ;` having the private ViewModel doesn't make any sense. This ViewModel class of mine has all my observable collections. That is much easier "for me" to maintain my code. But since it is not part of the actual ViewModel, I move it out of the class. See the updated UserControl class.